# How can I display one specific category (Lund,Cyklar and Kultur) with PHP?

Tags: php, html

How can I display one specific category (Lund, Cyklar and Kultur) with Php?

I wanna display only posts from ex Lund on a page.

```
<form action="<?php $self ?>" method="post">
    <h2>LundaBlogg</h2>
    <div class="fname">
        <label for="name"><p>Namn:</p></label><input name="name" type="text" cols="20"/>
    </div>
    <div class="femail">
        <label for="email"><p>Epost:</p></label><input name="email" type="text" cols="20"/>
    </div>
    <div class="where">
        <label for="lund"><p>Skriv ditt blogg ämne:</p></label>
        <input name="lund" type="text" cols="20"/>
    </div>
    <p>Starta tråden med att posta något:</p>
    <textarea name="post" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
    </br>
    <p>Välj kategori som du vill lägga din post i:</p>
    <select name="LundaBlogg" size="1">
        <option value="Lund">Lund</option>
        <option value="Cyklar">Cyklar</option>
        <option value="Kultur">Kultur</option>
    </select>
    </br>
    </br>
    <input name="send" type="hidden"/>
    <p><input type="submit" value="skicka"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: What? Can you be more specific? What are you trying to do? What is your database structure?

Comment: I can display all posts but I can not display a specicfic post from ex Lund.

Comment: This is my Php-code:   http://snipt.org/vVE1

Comment: Are you trying to display posts of a selected category

Comment: @Sherin Jose  Yes, thats correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM shouts WHERE LOWER(`LundaBlogg`)='lund' ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$result = @mysql_query("$query") or die('<p class="error">Det blev fel när du försökte hämta blogg inläggen från databasen.</p>');
```

Comment: Thanks, Im gonna try your code now ...